# Android Drawer with button to open it that moves with the drawer

Tags: android, drawer

The question says it all. I know how to implement a drawer with the drawerlayout, but i have no idea how to place a button next to the drawer (to show the drawer) that moves along with the drawer.

Comment: Did you mean the button to show the drawer right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle myDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, myDrawerLayout, R.drawable.my_icon_for_drawer_toggle,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

myDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(myDrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is sliding menu.
Look at this Github project which also provides example code for it

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Hope this helped!